# .htaccess works fine in local machine but not in server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am developing a website in core PHP and I want the pages to automatically redirect to my custom page (404.php) when someone enters invalid URL after the domain name. For example, I have a URL like www.abcdefg.com/abcd.php and if someone enters www.abcdefg.com/abzzcd.php, instead of showing the 404 error, I want to display the custom message.

It works fine in the local machine (XAMPP - localhost). Website is hosted in HostDime.

```
​<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sunday/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sunday/404.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled in the server?

Comment: @PraveenKumar : I don't know that sir. Can you please tell me about how to check it ?

Comment: vps?  windows vps?

Comment: @WEBjuju : nope sir.

Comment: how can i change the [mod_rewrite] permissions from cpanel ? I am not the admin user so I dont have the command line access.

Comment: you need to disclose the type of hosting

Comment: "I want" is always a good start, but you haven't shared anyhting about thr problem yet. What **exactly** is not working on the other server? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your suggestions and help. I got the solution by myself.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /admin/production/page_403.html
```

Simply added this at the end of my code and it works perfectly !

Thank you.